# a variation on the chain rule

Tags: analysis, chain-rule

Consider the composition of functions $A = B \circ C$ and choose 2 of the functions to be differentiable, so there are $\binom{3}{2}$ cases

1. (Chain rule) If B and C are differentiable, then A is differentiable.
2. If A and B are differentiable, is C differentiable?
3. Likewise, if A and C are differentiable, is B differentiable?

The only way I see so far is to use the inverse function theorem, but I feel this is not the simplest approach, plus it introduces the additional hypothesis of requiring non zero derivative. So is there a better approach?

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable, $g(x)=x^2$ is differentiable, and $f(g(x))$ is differentiable. Same with $g(f(x))$.

Comment: Take $B$ or $C$ constant. Then $A$ is differentiable no matter how weird the remaining function is.